# Cannot hide tab named "General" in crm 2011

Tags: javascript, tabs, dynamics-crm-2011

recently I've faced with strange behavior of **Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("bla-bla").setVisible(false)** 
On custom form I have a couple of tabs (one of them contains subgrid) hidden by default and depending on some conditions I need to show some of them. I do it by following JS in form.onLoad:

```
function onLoadInvoiceLineForm(){
    var parameters = {};
    parameters = Xrm.Page.context.getQueryStringParameters();
    type = parameters["p_CForm"];
    Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("gff").setVisible(type=="ff");
    Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("sff").setVisible(type=="ff");
    Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("ctc").setVisible(type=="ctc");
}
```

here I have a problem with tab "gff" which is the "General" tab on the form - it cannot be hidden by SetVisible(false). I've recreated this tab again and again, sorted fields in all of the available tabs on the form, renamed this tab, but without any luck - it is still shown.
Any other tab can be shown/hidden with setVisible(), except "General".

Probably, some of you have met with this and know the fix? Please, help.

thanks,
Gennadii

Comment: Can you add a screenshot like Gudio has in his answer below?

Answer (score 1):

The `Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get` method accepts the index or the name of the tab, so first you need to check if the name (and not just the label) is `General`

[image]

As you can see the default name for the tab `General` is a `GUID`.

There is also a case when you can't hide a tab, it's when is the only tab left in your form.

If for example you have 3 tabs, and you try to hide all 3, the third one will still be visible.

Comment: thanks Guido,
I use tab name "gff", not a label "General". but it doesn't help.